# LGPL and AGPL combo - how?

Tags: lgpl, license, agpl

I'm writing a library and I want to license it so that if you modify and use it, even at a network service, you will need to disclose the modified source code of the library (as in the AGPL) but it would only apply to the library itself (like the LGPL). Is there any way to do this, preferably retaining compatibility with AGPL?

I am the sole copyright owner.

Answer (score 4):

If you're the sole copyright owner, you can write an exception text, to be attached to the [AGPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html), similar to the [GPL-3.0 Interface Exception](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-interface-exception.html), and it may look like this:

> Linking *[name of library]* statically or dynamically with other
> modules is making a combined work based on *[name of library]*. Thus,
> the terms and conditions of the GNU Affero General Public License,
> version 3 ("AGPLv3") cover the whole combination.
>
> As a special exception, the copyright holders of *[name of library]*
> give you permission to combine *[name of library]* with
> independent modules that communicate with *[name of library]* solely
> through the *[name of library's interface]* interface, and exclude the
> source code of those independent modules from the
> Corresponding Source of section 13 of the AGPLv3, provided
> that you do not modify the *[name of library's interface]* interface and provided that those independent modules are themselves not licensed under the AGPLv3.
>
> Note that people who make modified versions of *[name of library]* are
> not obligated to grant this special exception for their modified
> versions; it is their choice whether to do so. The AGPLv3 gives
> permission to release a modified version without this exception; this
> exception also makes it possible to release a modified version which
> carries forward this exception. If you modify the *[name of library's
> interface]* interface, this exception does not apply to your modified
> version of *[name of library]*, and you must remove this exception
> when you distribute your modified version.
>
> This exception is an additional permission under section 7 of the
> AGPLv3.

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.